# Finding prime numbers with a custom IsPrime method

Tags: java, methods, numbers

I started learning Java about one month ago and today I saw this question I couldn't solve.

The question was:

> Write a method named `isPrime`, which takes an integer as an argument and returns `true`
>   if the argument is a prime number, or `false` otherwise. Demonstrate the method in a complete program.

And the second part says:

> Use the `isPrime` method that you wrote in previous program in a program that 
>   stores a list of all the prime numbers from `1` through `100` in a file.

Here's my code, which doesn't work:

```
import java.io.*;

public class PrimeNumbers {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("PrimeNumber.txt");

        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            isPrime(i); 
            outputFile.println("Prime nums are:" + i);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isPrime (int j) {

        int i;  
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            if (i == j) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing an "if" statement. *if* is prime {write to file}

Comment: You also don't need to check all the way up to j to see if it's prime, only sqrt(j)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition for returning `true` in `isPrime` - `if (i == j)` - can never be met, since it's inside a loop whose condition is `j < i`. Instead, just return `true` after the loop. If the loop ends without returning `false`, you know for sure that the input number is prime.

Your code that uses `isPrime` is not checking the value returned by this method. You must check it in order to decide whether to write the number to the output file.

Comment: @trejder -1 for encouraging answering homework / do it for me questions.

Comment: @Unihedron You're welcome to have your own point of view. But, then again... good question, why're editing and improving such homework questions, instead of flagging / closing them, as I do?

Comment: @Unihedron Just to set the record straight - I didn't do the homework for anybody. I just explained the problem in the OP's code without writing the code for them.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PrimeNumbers
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter primeNumbersWriter = new PrintWriter("PrimeNumber.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            // You didn't do anything with the return value of isPrime()
            if (isPrime(i))
            {
                primeNumbersWriter.println("Prime numbers are: " + i);
            }
        }

        // Please close writers after using them
        primeNumbersWriter.close();
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int prime)
    {
        // Do not use the number to check for prime as loop variable, also it's
        // sufficient to iterate till the square root of the number to check
        for (int number = 2; number < Math.sqrt(prime); number++)
        {
            if (prime % number == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // You didn't always return a value, it won't let you compile otherwise
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Unihedron: I added explanations in form of comments now. Still, a working solution is not a reason to downvote because that's what answers are supposed to provide.

Comment: No that is not correct. A working solution is only *part* of a useful and good answer. Code-Only answers are subject to downvoting (and eventually deletion) because they add no significant value to the site. For more information [check meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/1803692)

Answer (score 1):

> ***`Prime Number`***
>  A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater
>   than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself.

---

*What should be the logic?*

- Pass a number to method.
- Use loop to start a check of modulo `%` to find *at least* one number which can divide the passed number.
- Check until we reached the value `passedNumber`.
- If the modulo gives `0` for atleast one, it's not prime thank god!
- If modulo is not `0` for any number ...oh man it's `Prime.`

*What are the problems in your code?*

- You are looping correctly but using the variable `j` which is the limit and you are incrementing it!
- If you want to loop through `i < j` how can the condition `i == j` be true?
- If method is returning `boolean` why are you using method as `void`! Use that returned value.
- You can just return false at the end if divisor not found!

We did it...Just try now!

Answer (score 0):

about isPrime: First of all, u should loop `for( j = 2; j*j <= i; j++)`

*the reason for this loop is that if a number isn't prime, its factor must be less or equal to the squared root of i, so there is no need to loop after that point*
now, if loop didn't return false - return true`

about second function: use if before checking isPrime - `if(isPrime(i)) {add i to list}`

Comment: While what you are saying is completely true, you should definitely explain **why** this is the case. Why is the loop better the way you write it. Some people just don't know *that* much already..

Comment: OP is not guaranteed to understand `sqrt(i)` as what it is. Please tailor your answer to the askers level of expertise...

Answer (score -1):

see here is your solution.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Testing {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            System.out.println("Enter number to check if prime or not ");
            while (number != 0) {
                number = scnr.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Does %d is prime? %s %s  %s %n", number,
                        isPrime(number), isPrimeOrNot(number), isPrimeNumber(number));
            }
        }


        /*
         * Java method to check if an integer number is prime or not.
         * @return true if number is prime, else false
         */
        public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
            int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
            for (int i = 2; i < sqrt; i++) {
                if (number % i == 0) {
                    // number is perfectly divisible - no prime
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


        /*
         * Second version of isPrimeNumber method, with improvement like not
         * checking for division by even number, if its not divisible by 2.
         */
        public static boolean isPrimeNumber(int number) {
            if (number == 2 || number == 3) {
                return true;
            }
            if (number % 2 == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
            for (int i = 3; i < sqrt; i += 2) {
                if (number % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }


        /*
         * Third way to check if a number is prime or not.
         */
        public static String isPrimeOrNot(int num) {
            if (num < 0) {
                return "not valid";
            }
            if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
                return "not prime";
            }
            if (num == 2 || num == 3) {
                return "prime number";
            }
            if ((num * num - 1) % 24 == 0) {
                return "prime";
            } else {
                return "not prime";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack Overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.